# How do I send an email automatically after displaying it

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have made an add-in so when you click the button it will set some variables then call the send function. When doing this via reply it is impossible to call the send function so I am using the `mailItem.Display()` function to pop the email out and then call the send function however the send function is always called before the window has fully opened so it does not work.

I have made the send function get called in the `NewInspectorEventHandler` which causes it to open too soon. The `InspectorActivate` event also gets called before the window is open.

Comment: A [mcve] would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) event is fired when an inspector becomes the active window, either as a result of user action or through program code. That is where you may call the `Send` method to submit an item composed inline.

Comment: Hi Eugene. This is the best solution I could think of and it almost works perfectly. However the display function seems to display the window but it does not become the active window. When the inspector opens if you click off and click back on it works. How would I go about making it active via code?

Comment: `MailItem.GetInspector().Activate`

Comment: Inside my buttons click function.  <br/>
`public void Seperate1_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{            
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = OutlookAddIn1.Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] as Outlook.MailItem;            
mailItem.Display();
mailItem.GetInspector.Activate();
}`

Inside Inspector Activate Event Handler

`private void OutlookApplication_InspectorActivate()
{
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
mailItem.Send();
}`

Should this work?

Comment: Did you try to run it?

Comment: Yes and it still made me click off the window and click back onto it. I assume I must be calling it in the wrong palce.

Comment: Typically you shouldn't call the Activate `method` at all. Do you have any other add-ins or code that may affect this?

Comment: I do have it so that when the send function is called it is interrupted to display a send options form. I am also calling I guess the initialization part of the activate function inside of the NewInspector Event Handler